# Get subgraphs: communities of graph g

Tags: functions, graphs-and-networks

I have a graph `g`. I want a set of graphs `c` which holds the community subgraphs of `g`.

I tried `c = Subgraph[g, FindGraphCommunities[g]]`, but it only outputs the whole graph `g`. I see in the documentation that `FindGraphCommunities` returns a list of vertices, this may be why. How do I also get the edges?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your query:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
   7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8}];

coms = FindGraphCommunities[g];

Row[Subgraph[g, #, VertexLabels -> "Name"] & /@ coms]
```

[image]

Comment: FYI you can use the notation `1 <-> 2` for undirected edge.

Comment: @SimonWoods: Yeah, should have done that before pasting code...